# How can I efficiently connect a web frontend to my server application?

Tags: backend

Our server product is currently in desktop form and we're trying to move it over to a service while providing a web-based frontend to make it easier to monitor and administrate.  Not having a ton of web experience I'm struggling with figuring out the best way to do this.

For a first pass, our requirements are pretty basic.  We want to be able to view the status of the various components of our system and real-time monitor the logs that it spits out.

My thought is to add some sort of TCP-based interface to our server application that can be used by a separate web framework running on a different server somewhere.  For basic status messages this seems straightforward: the user connects to the web interface, it queries the server application for the current status, then displays that status to the user.  It gets a bit more complicated when it comes to the log streaming.  I'm concerned that constantly requesting the latest logs from the server application, especially if there is a separate connection for each user, will put more stress on the server application than we would like.

It seems that ideally the web server will open a single persistent connection to the server application, and the server application will push data to the web server anytime the status changes or a new message is logged.  The web server will then cache this data and "forward" it to all connected users.  This way the amount of work that the server application is doing is largely fixed and is not dependent on the number of users currently connected to the server.

My questions are:

1. Does this fundamentally make sense?
2. How should I go about doing this?  Is it something that a web framework should be able to handle (I'm leaning towards lift, but not tied to anything right now) or will I need to write my own intermediate caching layer that keeps a persistent connection to the server application, but serves the data to the web server as needed?  Is my best bet to do this from scratch or are there already well tested solutions for this type of thing?

As I mentioned I'm a pretty big noob when it comes to any sort of web development so anything that even just points me in the right direction will help.

Comment: Ganglia might be a partial solution for graphing server metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Is your product a hardware device that puts out info to something like a syslog, or a software app that monitors the info, and has a real-time log display and stores that info in text log files? You didn't mention anything about pulling the data from a database, so I'm assuming it's not storing it in one?

I'm not sure I understand completely the pieces of the puzzle, but with that in mind, a couple thoughts come to mind...

- Have your server app store that log data in a db somewhere that the web server can access, then use an AJAX-enabled web frontend to refresh the 'log view' section of the web page every x seconds looking for just new entries to the log to append to the view
- XMPP/Jabber might also be able to play a part in what you're doing - the protocol is used in some IM clients for real-time messaging. It sounds a bit like you're wanting this to work in a 'push messaging' kind of way. So, possibly it could make sense to setup a jabber server alongside the web server (could probably be the same server, depending on load), and then in your server app send the messages to the jabber server via XMPP, which will relay them out to the listeners, which would be XMPP/Jabber clients - I know googletalk can act as a client, and iChat can, and I believe some others. Or you can possibly write a Java client to run in the browser (I'm not a Java person, though...)
  And then write a minimal web app to handle the administration side of things for the app.
  You could probably also handle the administration side of things over XMPP - send it a message to 'change x setting to y' and possibly do it all on just the one server without a need for a separate web/jabber server.

But these are things I'd look at.

www.jivesoftware.org still has their jabber server available free I believe, and I have no association with them - just something I experimented with at one time and thought it was very interesting.

Greg

Comment: Right now it's basically just spitting out logs to flat files.  In the future I imagine it will either continue to do something like that or put it out to a database.  The XMPP stuff is probably overkill here, but the DB idea may be the best way to go as it will also facilitate any sort of log querying, etc.

That said, I guess I still just have the general question of if we are pulling from a DB, what's the standard practice so that 10 connected users aren't making 10 separate DB queries (or whatever the data store might be) to pull the exact same data?

Comment: Should have been more clear in the last comment.  "a software app that monitors the info, and has a real-time log display and stores that info in text log files?" is pretty much exactly what we have.  The realtime log viewer is built directly into our app, there's no second application monitoring anything.

Comment: I may be talking over my head here, I'm new here, and many things on this site seem over my head so far... but hopefully I'll learn more in the process as well. How many log file lines are you talking per timeframe - minute, hour, day, etc...? Can you easily parse those lines into separate database colums? Most database servers these days have some way to keep the db in memory, so queries are quick. Put a LogID idx on the table,and base the queries on a 'greater than last LogID' query, and handle the pg updat in an AJAX kind of way, and you're passing minimal data for the partial page refresh.